# Rewrite URLS without affecting old search engine results

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've run a games site for over 5 years and I'm currently redesigning from scratch. My current site uses ugly urls (?gameid=123) which I want to prettify (games/123).
The problem is my site is indexed by google and I don't want to break old urls and I don't know how to do this.

At the same time, it would be good if I could update the urls that show up on Google without ruining my position in the results.
So currently, if I look up "Bunny Invasion GPStudios" the top result is my site:
www.gpstudios.com/playgame.php?gameid=29
It would be good if I could update it to say www.gpstudios.com/games/29 or www.gpstudios.com/games/bunny-invasion-2

I've raided google and it seems as though few people are concerned with this problem. Perhaps I'm not phrasing it well.
Please help.

Comment: [Change page URLs with 301 redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+playgame\.php\?gameid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /games/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^games/(\d+)/?$ playgame.php?gameid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.

It's possible to use links like `www.gpstudios.com/games/29/bunny-invasion` or `www.gpstudios.com/games/29/just-for-SEO`.
For that just change the line without `?$`:

```
RewriteRule ^games/(\d+)/ playgame.php?gameid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I've just been thinking, I would preferably like my urls to be 'games/bunny-invasion' not games/29/bunny-invasion. I'm not sure how I'd do this without some PHP/mysql. Also, would my search engine results update to show the new urls once the pretty URLS are implemented?

Comment: You can redirect the same way, but not from .htaccess

Comment: In that case I think I might do all of the internal URL prettifying in PHP. Or is that a bad idea? Also, will my existing search engine results update when I redirect them to the pretty URL? (Google most importantly)

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's not a bad idea, but in my point of view, it is not helpful. You can place the number at the end, if you prefer. `games/bunny-invasion/29` or `games/bunny-invasion-29`

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the old URLs can still be reached. Next, instead of serving up the page, just send a header with a 301 (or some other appropriate) response (read more about response codes at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and a redirect to the new URL.

You can read up on PHP:s `header` function at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score -1):

You have to use 301 (permanent) redirects from the old URLs to the new ones. It's called URL rewriting and is a common issue in the SEO industry. Each and every URL should be "rewrited" to a new page.

Use a .htaccess file at the root of your project :

```
Redirect /old/url /new/url [L,R=301]
```

You can use regexp to ease the job :

```
Redirect /games/(\d+) playgame.php?gameid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

More information here : http://www.beyondink.com/howtos/301-redirect.php